# How to make the JBoss 5.0 shared library available?

Tags: jboss

I want to share a jar file for two war in the same instance.

For test, I make the jboss folder and war file like this.

1)JBoss Folder

server/default

-- deploy/

```
 -- myApp.war
```

-- lib/

```
 -- test_1.2.jar(only one method to output "1.2")
```

2)WAR

myApp.war

-- META-INF/

-- WEB-INF/

```
 -- class/

    -- myservlet(reference class test to output the version)

 -- lib/

    -- test_1.1.jar(only one method to output "1.1")
```

I hope the shared library could override the jar file in WAR,

but i still get the version "1.1".

it means that the jar file in WAR worked, but not the jar in the "server/default/lib".

Comment: I Know，
I need to set  <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="true"> to change the ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered packing both WARs into an EAR and moving to JAR to the `lib/` folder in the EAR? This makes it portable and will also work on JBoss AS 7 and later.